# Second iteration crash - order irrelevant

Tags: c++, memory, crash, cuda

To save on global memory transfers, and because all of the steps of the code work individually, I have tried to combine all of the kernals into a single kernal, with the first 2 (of 3) steps being done as **device** calls rather than **global** calls.
This is failing in the second half of the first step.

There is a function that I need to call twice, to calculate the 2 halves of an image. Regardless of the order the image is calculated in, it crashes on the second iteration.

After examining the code as well as I could, and running it multiple times with different return points, I have found what makes it crash.

```
__device__
void IntersectCone( float* ModDistance,
                float* ModIntensity,
                float3 ray,
                int threadID,
                modParam param )
{

bool ignore = false;

float3 normal = make_float3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
float3 result = make_float3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
float normDist = 0.0f;
float intensity = 0.0f;

float check = abs( Dot(param.position, Cross(param.direction,ray) ) );
if(check > param.r1 && check > param.r2)
    ignore = true;

float tran = param.length / (param.r2/param.r1 - 1);
float length = tran + param.length;
float Lsq = length * length;
float cosSqr = Lsq / (Lsq + param.r2 * param.r2);

//Changes the centre position?
float3 position = param.position - tran * param.direction;

float aDd = Dot(param.direction, ray);
float3 e = position * -1.0f;
float aDe = Dot(param.direction, e);
float dDe = Dot(ray, e);
float eDe = Dot(e, e);
float c2 = aDd * aDd - cosSqr;
float c1 = aDd * aDe - cosSqr * dDe;
float c0 = aDe * aDe - cosSqr * eDe;

float discr = c1 * c1 - c0 * c2;

if(discr <= 0.0f)
    ignore = true;

if(!ignore)
{
    float root = sqrt(discr);
    float sign;

    if(c1 > 0.0f)
        sign = 1.0f;
    else
        sign = -1.0f;

    //Try opposite sign....?
    float3 result = (-c1 + sign * root) * ray / c2;


    e = result - position;
    float dot = Dot(e, param.direction);        
    float3 s1 = Cross(e, param.direction);          
    float3 normal = Cross(e, s1);

    if( (dot > tran) || (dot < length) )
    {
        if(Dot(normal,ray) <= 0)
        {
            normal = Norm(normal);    //This stuff (1)
            normDist = Magnitude(result);
            intensity = -IntensAt1m * Dot(ray, normal) / (normDist * normDist);
        }
    }
}
ModDistance[threadID] = normDist; and this stuff (2)
ModIntensity[threadID] = intensity; 
}
```

There are two things I can do to to make this not crash, both off which negate the point of the function: If I do not try to write to ModDistance[] and ModIntensity[], or if I do not write to normDist and intensity.

First chance exceptions are thrown by the code above, but not if either of the blocks commented out.
Also, The program only crashes the second time this routine is called.

Have been trying to figure this out all day, any help would be fantastic.

The code that calls it is:

```
int subrow = threadIdx.y + Mod_Height/2;
int threadID = subrow * (Mod_Width+1) + threadIdx.x;        
int obsY = windowY + subrow;
float3 ray = CalculateRay(obsX,obsY);

if( !IntersectSphere(ModDistance, ModIntensity, ray, threadID, param) )
{
    IntersectCone(ModDistance, ModIntensity, ray, threadID, param);
}

subrow = threadIdx.y;
threadID = subrow * (Mod_Width+1) + threadIdx.x;        
obsY = windowY + subrow;
ray = CalculateRay(obsX,obsY);

if( !IntersectSphere(ModDistance, ModIntensity, ray, threadID, param) )
{
    IntersectCone(ModDistance, ModIntensity, ray, threadID, param);
}
```

Comment: The symptom of the error was showing in a different place than the source of the error. The entire kernal was too large, and so could not assign enough registers.

Comment: The two lines you've called out perhaps provide a starting point. (1) What does the `Norm()` function look like?  I expect it to return a scalar, not a vector? Same question for `Magnitude()`. (2) I can only see this line crashing if `threadID` was out of bounds.

Comment: Ah just saw your comment.  Good find.

Comment: Running out of registers will not cause a memory access error like you are seeing, it will just result in register values being spilled to and later filled from (local) device memory.  To diagnose the memory error, you should try cuda_memcheck.

Comment: You say you merge serveral kernels into one "uber-kernel". Could you show that piece of code and a brief description, what functions do? I would like to see a broad look at your kernel, not the detail internals. Also, how ModDistance and ModIntensity are declared? Are those shared arrays? Global?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't registers specifically, but I have now fixed the problem. Previously I was using a thread Block size of 32*16, the maximum allowed on my device. I cut this down to 32*8, and now it runs perfectly fine. When I also thought to check the error from the kernal launch, it was a 'CudaErrorLaunchOutOfResources'. So I don't know how it actually managed to run and change memory values in the first place.

Comment: Kernel launches are asynchronous, and so you were probably not actually running the first time successfully.  In the interest of getting this question off the unanswered list, I'm posting an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel is running out of resources.  As posted in the comments, it was giving the error `CudaErrorLaunchOutOfResources`.

To avoid this, you should use a `__launch_bounds__` specifier to specify the block dimensions you want for your kernel.  This will force the compiler to ensure there are enough resources.  See the CUDA programming guide for details on `__launch_bounds__`.